# working with openweathermap api getting an unauthorized error

Tags: javascript

I need some help understanding why this api is not liking my format.
getting the 401 error but I am giving the server the appid here is my code, thanks for the help!

```
       function getForecast(){
          var city = $("#city").val();
          var days = $("#days").val();
          var appID ='APIKEY';


    if(city != '' && days != ''){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily? 
         q='+city+'&units=metric&cnt='+days+'&APPID='+appID+'',
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume that you have defined the actual 'APIKEY' somewhere such as your .env file?

I might expect to see something like:
`var appID = process.ENV.APIKEY`

If you haven't declared the actual APIKEY anywhere first you need to get one from openweathermap and then I suggest you research Environment Variables so you know how to call them.

Comment: Hi,
I defined the apikey here:
 var appID ='APIKEY';

I just didn't include what the actual key was when posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I was calling the api code wrong.
instead of:

```
     http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily? 
     q='+city+'&units=metric&cnt='+days+'&APPID='+appID+
```

I needed to call this:

```
      http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
       q=London,us&mode=json&appid
```

Thanks anyways